# How Unity Raycast Detect the point "Out" of collider, not only just "In"

Tags: unity-game-engine, point, raycasting, hit

By using Physics.Raycast in Unity, we can get hit information easily with the point, normal, collider name...  But how can I get the "point" where ray go out of the collider?

Many thanks for your time thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try casting a reverse ray only on the collider that has been hit so that you can determine where the ray enters from the back? The code below might work.

```
RaycastHit firstHit;
Ray firstRay = new Ray (origin, direction);
Physics.Raycast (firstRay, out firstHit, distance);

Vector3 reverseOrigin = firstRay.origin + (firstRay.direction * distance);
RaycastHit reverseHit;
Ray reverseRay = new Ray (reverseOrigin, (firstRay.direction * -1));
firstHit.collider.Raycast (reverseRay, out reverseHit, distance);
```